# Oracle Update Query - single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to run the below query -

```
SELECT s.forename,
  hss.forename,
  s.surname,
  hss.surname,
  s.dob,
  s.ethnic_or,
  hss.ethnicity,
  s.person_id,
  hs.term_id,
  hs.status_text
FROM people s
INNER JOIN headcount_submission_student hss
ON hss.import_stud_id = s.person_id
INNER JOIN headcount_submission hs
ON hs.submission_student_id = hss.submission_student_id
WHERE s.ethnic_or          IS NULL
AND NOT hss.ethnicity      IS NULL
AND hs.term_id             = 48
GROUP BY s.forename,
  hss.forename,
  s.surname,
  hss.surname,
  s.dob,
  s.ethnic_or,
  hss.ethnicity,
  s.person_id,
  hs.term_id,
  hs.status_text
ORDER BY s.surname;
```

As an UPDATE query, as I want to update all the values in s.ethnic_or column with the values from hss.ethnicity

I've tried various different ways, but so far no joy. Can anyone suggest something?

I've been getting

> SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

when trying this

```
UPDATE People t1
SET
  (
    t1.ethnic_or
  )
  =
  (SELECT hss.ethnicity
  FROM headcount_submission_student hss
  INNER JOIN headcount_submission hs
  ON hs.submission_student_id = hss.submission_student_id
  WHERE NOT hss.ethnicity    IS NULL
  AND term_id                 = 48
  AND NOT hss.import_stud_id IN (136791, 140481, 140490, 140582)
  )
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT NULL
  FROM headcount_submission_student hss
  INNER JOIN headcount_submission hs
  ON hs.submission_student_id = hss.submission_student_id
  WHERE NOT hss.ethnicity    IS NULL
  AND hs.term_id                 = 48
  AND hss.import_stud_id      = t1.person_id
  )
AND t1.ethnic_or IS NULL;
```

Comment: The subquery is clearly returning more than one row.  You will need to modify it to return a single row for each People row being updated.

Answer (score 0):

First tip, don't alias a table "t1", use an alias that is meaningful.  In your case, the table is people, either don't alias or use something like "ppl".  Your SQL will be easier to read.

Now, I took some liberties and instead of addressing the sub-query that is returning more than a single-row, I've re-written your update as the following using a subquery.  In the sub-query, I've tried to replicate your joins and filters to get the people missing the ethnicity but where is it populated in the other tables.  Take a look as this alternative.

```
update
(select people.ethnic_or, hss.ethnicity
from   people
inner join headcount_submission_student hss on (people.person_id = hss.import_stud_id)
inner join head_count_submission hs on (hs.submission_student_id = hss.submission_student_id and hs.term_id = 48)
where people.ethnic_or IS NULL
  AND hss.ethnicity IS NOT NULL
  and hss.import_stud_id NOT IN (136791, 140481, 140490, 140582))
set   ethnic_or = ethnicity;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I now get the error - SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
01779. 00000 -  "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which
           map to a non-key-preserved table.
*Action:   Modify the underlying base tables directly.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  I think made an assumption on your data model, specificaly on your people table.  Does it have a PK?